# preg_match() returns null with curl response

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I'm trying to retrieve an authorisation code from an API. I'm using the following function:

```
function getAuthToken($url, $email, $password) {

    $params = array(
        'SCOPE'     => '****',
        'EMAIL_ID'  => $email,
        'PASSWORD'  => $password,
    );

    $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match('~.+?AUTHTOKEN=(.+?)\s~', $result, $matches);

    return $matches[1];

}
```

This returns NULL. If I var_dump($result), I get:

```
string(87) "# #Mon Jul 29 04:01:09 PDT 2019 AUTHTOKEN=**** RESULT=TRUE "
```

if I copy the text and create a variable and run preg_match on the variable, I get the required result.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Output the `urlencode` -d version of the value, that should make it easy to spot if there are any characters/byte sequences in there that you can’t “see” otherwise.

Comment: Does   a simpler `preg_match('~AUTHTOKEN=(\S+)~', $result, $matches);` work?

Comment: Thanks, using `preg_match('~AUTHTOKEN=(.+?)\s~', $result, $matches);` seems to have worked. When I have time, I will try `urlencode` to see if I can work out waht was going wrong…

Comment: If there were newlines in the result (like before the AUTHTOKEN line), then the leading `.+?` expression would prevent the regex from matching unless you use the `s` modifier (so the dot metacharacter matches the newline).

Comment: I think you've got it, I think there are newlines actually.